# add click event to polygon class c#

Tags: c#, wpf, events, click, extension-methods

I have a class with a Polygon.

my program print the polygon that in the class, and I want to add click event to the class. when click on the polygon, the event will run.

I want to add click event, extension method, something like this (just instead this- click event):

```
public static class extensionMethodPolygon
{
    public static void func1(this Polygon p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("polygon");
    }
}
```

but I don't know how.

What I did:

```
        Polygon []arr = new Polygon[72];
        for (int i = 0; i < 72; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = allPolygons[i].Polygon;
            arr[i].MouseUp += MainWindow_MouseUp;
            arr[i].MouseDown+=MainWindow_MouseUp;
        }
        foreach (Polygon item in arr)
        {
            MyGrid.Children.Add(item);
        }
```

and:

```
    void MainWindow_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Polygon");
    }
```

But when i click, the event work just on part of the polygons, and I don't know why not on all the polygons.

Someone know how to solve the problem? or to offer another solution?

thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Polygon control doesn't have a click event but it does have mouse-down/mouse-up events you can handle as such:

**XAML:**

```
<Polygon MouseDown="Polygon_MouseDown" MouseUp="Polygon_MouseUp" Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
private void Polygon_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Mouse Down!"); // Break Here For Debugging

    Polygon obj = sender as Polygon;
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
         obj.Width += 50;
    });
}

private void Polygon_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Mouse Up!"); // Break Here For Debugging

    Polygon obj = sender as Polygon;
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
         obj.Height += 50;
    });
}
```

Then you can include animation in your mouse-down/mouse-up event handlers if needed. Here is some documentation of [Mouse-Down](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.mousedown(v=vs.110).aspx) as well.

Comment: Thank you, but this do it very strange. I print a lot of from the polygons, and just in part of them the event works. Although i wrote all the polygons to the events. do yo know why?

Comment: Why? This is the proper way to handle the click events on a polygon control in wpf.

Comment: I edited the last comment. I wrote there what strange. thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do from the handlers?

Comment: I meanwhile just want to test this, so i did:   void Polygon_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("polygon");
        }

Comment: this work just on the part of the polygons. I added now to the question part of the code- maybe it can help. thank you.

Comment: For adding elements link your doing you need to invoke that action from the dispatcher. Unless errors are thrown they most likely are all working but the event isn't being raised to the point where it updates the UI. I'll update the code to show what I mean.

Comment: I copy your answer, but the problem isn't solve. it is steal work just in part. especially in the left-up parts.

Comment: Have you tried placing a breaking point in the handler to see if it is being fired or not?

Comment: Yes. the Polygons certainly registered to the event but for some reason when I click on polygon, the event don't occurs.

Comment: The handler is the method run to "handle" said event. Polygon_MouseDown is your handler. Did you break in there to see if it is run when you click? Also attaching your method to both mouse up and mouse down will run the method twice when you click on it fyi.

Comment: private void Polygon_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show("Mouse Down!");

            Polygon obj = sender as Polygon;
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
           /*(here i have breakpoint)*/     obj.Fill = Brushes.White;
            }));
        }  the event occurs just in part the polygons. i don't know why.

Comment: Sorry but your not understanding me. Just because you don't see the action take place doesn't mean it didn't happen. Did you place a break point in the handler method or not? If you place a break point in the method and it gets hit the method is indeed being run but the UI isn't being updated if it doesn't get hit the handler wasn't added to the element properly.

Comment: Sorry. i new in c#... i don't understand where I need place the breakpoint exactly. Do you can copy the code with the breakpoint here? thanks

Comment: I added comments showing where to place the break point. My suggestion is to look up a few C# and wpf tutorials and go over those then come back to this. If you don't have an understanding of events and handlers it will be very difficult to debug this issue.

Comment: OK. I success to find the problem. I have in addition the polygons, also textblocks. For some reason the textblock blocks the click on the polygon, even that the textblock no is there. If I remove the textblocks, all working. I thank you so much, and I sorry on the waste of your time.

Comment: It's not a waste of time at all, I merely want to help you get it resolved in the most efficient way possible. What may have happened if you were running over both the polygons and textboxes in the method you use to add the handler (Polygon_MouseDown) if you tried to do that to a textbox it would throw an exception when it hits Polygon obj = sender as Polygon. If that is the case you can encase that with: `if (sender.GetType().Equals(typeof(Polygon)) { "Add event method" }`